# Loading New Advanced Custom Fields Row With Ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I have a little jQuery modal. This modal has a slideshow of different works of art. I have over 40 different works all in a list (just the name of the work) and each has at least 3 pictures. What I want to do is load a specific repeater row of Advanced Custom Fields repeater field in the modal when I click on the listed work. I am getting the ID of the row by using a echoing a PHP counter and hiding the element with CSS.

I nearly have this working. I cannot workout how to return new row ID to the page template. When I call my function `my_ajax_callback()` on the page template I get this error;

```
Notice: Undefined index: newRowId
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

**Page Template**

```
<span class="rowId"><?php echo $count_parent_row++; ?></span>
```

**jQuery**

```
button.click(function(e){

    var lastRowId = $('.rowId:last').html();
    console.log( lastRowId );

    $.ajax({
        url: ajax_object.ajaxurl, 
        type: 'POST',
        data:{
            action: 'my_ajax_action', 
            newRowId: lastRowId
        },

        success: function( data ){
            console.log( data );
        }
    });
});
```

**functions.php**

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'ajax_enqueue_scripts' );
function ajax_enqueue_scripts(){
  wp_enqueue_script( 'ajaxHandle', get_template_directory_uri() . '/library/js/ajax.js', array('jquery'), '1.0', true );
  wp_enqueue_script( 'ajaxHandle' );
  wp_localize_script( 'ajaxHandle', 'ajax_object', array( 'ajaxurl' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ) ) );
}

add_action( 'wp_ajax_my_ajax_action', 'my_ajax_callback' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_my_ajax_action', 'my_ajax_callback' );
function my_ajax_callback() {

    $data = $_POST['newRowId']; 

    if(isset($_POST['newRowId']))
    {

        $title              = 'drawings'; 
        $title__singular    = 'drawing';
        $row                = get_field('list_of_'. $title);
        $rowNumber          = $data;
        $row_first          = $row[$rowNumber];
        echo $field         = $row_first[$title__singular . '_title'];

    wp_die();
    }
}
```